# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS not working sometimes

Tags: mysql, joomla, sql-like, sql-calc-found-rows

```
$query->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.title,i.fulltext,i.shorttext');
        $query->from('#__items as i');
$query->where('i.shorttext LIKE "%'.$word.'%");
```

with this condition everything is right and count of rows is real...for example if it return  21 items...it is real...(the real returned result is 21)

but in this code:

```
 $query->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.title,i.fulltext,i.shorttext');
            $query->from('#__items as i');
$query->where('i.shorttext LIKE "%'.$word.'%" 
            OR i.fulltext LIKE "%'.$word.'%" 
            OR i.title LIKE "%'.$word.'%"');
```

The code return count of rows to me 63! (3 times bigger the real one.)

of course both of them print real times (not dublicate).

what's the wrong?
tnx

---

I changed to this (added brackets around the three `or` conditions) and the problem solved.

```
 $query->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.title,i.fulltext,i.shorttext');
            $query->from('#__items as i');
$query->where('(i.shorttext LIKE "%'.$word.'%" 
            OR i.fulltext LIKE "%'.$word.'%" 
            OR i.title LIKE "%'.$word.'%")');
```

Comment: Does your statement have a `LIMIT` clause (you are not showing one)?  If it does not, then there is no purpose to `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Comment: What does the explain plan look like? Is it the same for the original and the fixed version or different? Also what is the `$query->where` syntax? Are you using something that might rerwrite the query as a `UNION`?

Comment: it's joomla base functions....but the rule is fixed. :)

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the actual SQL executed from both versions? Can you reproduce this by running the SQL in (say) MySQL query workbench?

Comment: To get the query you would use echo $query->dump();.

Answer (score 0):

The code returns 63, because your query returns 63 rows (or you changed the variable afterwards in PHP).

It's either a correct result or you extracted the number wrong. There's no magic from MySQL at this point.

Comment: but whole of records is 21!

Comment: Either the number is correct or you retrieve the number falsely.